# Getting this error No module named nifi_common in <script> in Apache Nifi

Tags: apache-nifi, jython

I have upgraded apache nifi to 1.16.2 from 1.14.0 and when i run the workflow , it throws error in executescript which uses a python[jython] script .

The error message is

o.a.nifi.processors.script.ExecuteScript ExecuteScript[id=ab5f3095-c796-1f20-b650-10d78f56f40d] Processing failed
org.apache.nifi.processor.exception.ProcessException: javax.script.ScriptException: ImportError: No module named nifi_common in

In my script i have imported nifi_common.

Comment: What's the `nifi_common`? Where did you get it?

Comment: I have a file called nifi_common.py which i have imported it to another file .
So i am using import nifi_common ,
But after the upgrade its not able to import this file , which may be the reason i am seeing the error 
ImportError: No module named nifi_common